# Delphi control/way to print text sideways

Tags: delphi, user-controls, label, orientation

I need a way to have a label (or something like it) print sideways.  I would really like it to work at design time if at all possible.

Is there any controls / mechanisms that anyone knows of to do this?  (Not .net controls please)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would probably get better results by searching the Delphi ThirdPartyTools forum archives using CodeNewsFast ( http://www.codenewsfast.com ) full text search, or by posting question on that forum directly.

Here's one label control that does rotated text, I think many controls are enabled to do this now, in one way or another:
http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item.aspx?id=18645

Here's link to another freeware label component, from a guy that's always provided good quality stuff:
http://www.scalabium.com/anglelbl.htm

I haven't used Delphi in a few years and I don't remember exactly, but I think many of the third party component sets (e.g., DevEx, TMS) had rotation as one of the properties for labels on their edit controls back even five or more years ago.

Here's link with info on nitty gritty details on how to roll-your-own rotated text:
http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips2003/a/bltip0703.htm

Comment: Thanks for the info.  For future searchers, I also found this: http://www.torry.net/pages.php?id=130